# How to connect Hyper-VM guest to point to point Ethernet network

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I'm trying to set up a point to point network to rsync a large set of files between Linux running under Hyper-V (Windows 10 host) and another Linux box.  I have set up a point to point ethernet connection between the two machines.  On the Windows side I have configured a static IP address of 10.0.0.1/24 and on the Linux box I have configured a static IP address of 10.0.0.2/24.  I am able to ping 10.0.0.2 from 10.0.0.1.

How do I now expose the 10.0.0.0 network to the Linux guest under Hyper-V?  I already have a virtual switch which has an External network connection type to the WiFi adapter.  I created a second virtual switch which has an External network connection type to Ethernet, but I do not see a way to connect a second virtual switch to the VM.  Inside the VM the network already appears as an Ethernet adapter (eth0) which actually goes to the virtual switch bound to WiFi, so I don't see anything in the VM I can do to route 10.0.0.0/24 (theoretically it should already be happening via the default route).

Comment: If there are additional details I need to include, please let me know what they are.

Comment: Try using just one External Switch in HYper-V (so make a connection in Hyper-V that sees your router). That is what I have done with a Linux guest machine in Hyper-V

Comment: Not sure what you mean... the current switch sees the router (WiFi)... the other is the point to point connection.  I'll try switching it though, will see if the VM can see the rest of the network after that.

Comment: You said you were trying to use two network devices on one guest. Try just one device

Comment: @John Yes, one to connect to Wifi and one to connect to Ethernet

Comment: That normally does not work in a VM unless you are using USB pass through for one if the devices

Comment: John I don't think he's using the wifi in the VM, just a virtual switch pointing to it. Michael, just set up a virtual switch pointing to the physical network connection. If you've done research the issue may be you've over complicated things: you're just trying to connect a virtual machine to either two, or just a different network device on the host.